# How to use variables in li:n-th child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title goes I am trying something like

```
 $("ul li:nth-child(' + xx + ') a").text() //this is coming as blank.
```

what is the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this format:

```
var xx = 4;
$("ul li:nth-child(" + xx + ") a").text()
```

You want to actually append to the string here to get what you want so it results in this:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4) a").text()
```